# Using Event Emitters in the UI Router Config function (Angular 2/4)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I've been able to import my custom TokenService into the UI Router config function (as shown below) without issue:

```
import { UIRouter, Category } from '@uirouter/core';

import { TokenService } from './_services/token.service';
import { NOAUTH_STATES } from './app.states';

export function routerConfigFn(router: UIRouter) {
  const transitionService = router.transitionService;

  router.trace.enable(Category.TRANSITION);

  transitionService.onStart({}, transition => {
    let token = sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');
    let unguarded = [];

    NOAUTH_STATES.forEach(state => unguarded.push(state.name));

    // EVENT EMITTER CODE (BELOW) GOES HERE

    if (unguarded.indexOf(transition.to().name) === -1) {
      let token = sessionStorage.getItem('access_token');

      if (!!token) {
        transition.injector().get(TokenService).tokenInfoGet(token).subscribe( // <--- HERE
          (data: any) => {
            return;
          },
          (error: any) => {
            transition.injector().get(TokenService).validate(retryGuardedRoute); // <-- AND HERE
          });
      } else {
        transition.injector().get(TokenService).validate(retryGuardedRoute); // <-- AND HERE
      }
    }
  });
}

// retryGuardedRoute is another method not shown here, but it uses the same
// transition.injector().get(TokenService) call to the validate method as
// shown in the 'error', and 'else' sections above
```

But as soon as I try and use an event emitter from the same service as opposed to the method calls shown above, I get a 'No Provider' error message. (code below, inserted at 'EVENT EMITTER GOES HERE' comment in the config code above):

```
transition.injector().get(TokenService).authorizeUpdated.subscribe(
  (data: any) => {
    console.log('waited...');
    if (data === true) {
      return;
    } else {
      return router.stateService.target('login');
    }
  },
  (error: any) => {
    console.log('waiting, now redirecting');
    return router.stateService.target('login');
  }
);
```

Is there additional setup required in my custom service or in the router config in order to successfully subscribe to an event emitter from within the config function, or is this not possible?

Comment: UPDATE: I've also tried setting authorizeUpdated as an observable (instead of an Event Emitter), and I'm still receiving the 'No Provider' error when I attempt to subscribe to it in my `router.config.ts` file. Not sure how I can get 'No Provider' for an event emitter, observable, and variable in a service that works when I'm accessing a method, something about that just doesn't *click* for me.

Comment: Your comment implies that you are getting `No Provider` when calling `authorizeUpdated`?  `No Provider` error happens during dependency injection, so it's probably happening within the `.get(TokenService)` call.  --
 Can you post the full code with the event emitter wired up so I can see the whole thing?  It's worth noting that subscribing to an event emitter *within the hook callback* seems like the wrong approach.  Your hook will be invoked for each transition, and each hook will create a *new subscription*.

Comment: I suggest you use something like a BehaviorSubject: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ui-router-angular-yswb2v?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Or if you only want to use an observable, do something like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ui-router-angular-sha9pz?file=app%2Flogin.component.ts

Comment: Many thank yous @ChrisT! I haven't had the time to fully implement the changes, but your suggestions for implementation of the BehaviorSubject definitely bought me some traction and got me past the No Provider error.